# AngularJS e2e test scenario hanging

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I had been off of my angular project for a month and when I came back to it, suddenly the e2e scenario hangs loading the page. It waits for about 2 minutes and then proceeds w/ the scenario. I can see in the lower left of the chrome browser "waiting for localhost". When I inspect Network w/ Chrome Dev tools, I do see "pending" requests for various '.js' files.

Other devs on the same project continue to run just fine. I just recently upgraded node:

```
node v0.10.19
karma v0.10.2
```

Other dev's machine works fine with:

```
node v0.10.18
karma v0.10.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes just be as simple as a syntax error in the scenario, try removing each test one by one, maybe that will uncover your problem?

Comment: ok, I'm willing to give it a shot. However, the fact the suite runs fine for other devs would seem to exclude that as a cause.

Comment: still no luck. I am able to run the scenarios by starting my local dev server and navigating to localhost:8000/test/e2e/all.html and it runs fine. :/  At least I can the tests now. 
Temp problem I guess as next step is to migrate all my tests to protractor.